# SSIS/SSDT 2015 Formatted Send Mail Body

Tags: ssis

I've created a very simple package that loops through folders (and subfolders), retrieving a list of files that exist and compiling them into a variable called str_AllFiles.  The ForEach loop does its thing, the script task to compile the string does its thing, and when it's all said and done the Send Mail task does its thing.  Everything works just fine...except that the resultant email that's generated comes out as hyperlinks to the actual files instead of just directory/file names.  The directory/file names are present, but they are all hyperlinks to the files themselves.

Is there any way to reformat the string variable or the Send Mail message source so that it's plain text?  I've seen some suggestions to use a script task to send the email as HTML, but when using that (from here:  http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/08/sending-mail-within-ssis-part-2-script.html), but I keep getting an exception error that I can't track down when coding this.  To be fair, I'm hard-coding the FROM, TO, and SUBJECT when using the HTML version, which may very well be the issue here.

Any ideas on this?  How do I transform the message source so that it's plain text and not a page of hyperlinks?

Comment: It can be challenging for us to diagnose a code issue with no code shown. Specifically, what does the body of the email text look like before you pass it to the send mail task?

Comment: Well, there's nothing to it, really.  It's a simple list of files, such as:

\\nasdrive\folder\file.txt
\\nasdrive\folder\file2.txt

And so on.

Comment: So, you're not explicitly adding html tags to the email you're generating and instead you are suffering outlook being _helpful_ by making UNC paths into hyperlinks?

Comment: If that's the case, I'd see whether using `<pre>...</pre>` with your body doesn't just take care of the behavior